# Left aligment column table text

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

This is a simple question. There are too many white spaces between the words of the 3rd column. Is it possible to adjust the text to have just one space between 'commas' and 'words'?

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{float,threeparttable,booktabs,fontspec}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\caption{Estructura del guión de entrevista: apartados, componentes y temas}
 \label{tab:guionentrevistas}
\centering
 \begin{threeparttable}
    \begin{tabular}{llp{0.4\textwidth}}
    \toprule
            \bf Apartado &  \bf Componente & \bf Tema \\
            \midrule
         Presentación & Explicaciones & Proyecto, preguntas, registro, lenguaje, dinámica.\\
         Descripciones &  Perfil       & Formación, trayectoria, profesión.\\ 
        Cuestionario  & Extensión 15M & Acciones, organización, entornos, actividades, opinión\\ 
                      & Objetivos 15M & Manifestaciones, acampadas, destinatarios\\
                   & Estructura 15M   & Actores, procesos, roles, organigrama, herencias, gestión del consenso\\
                   & Mentalidad 15M   & Ideas, orígenes, creencias\\
                   & Comunicación 15M   & Ideas\\

\bottomrule
\end {tabular}
    \begin{tablenotes}
      \small
      \item
    \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I had to edit your code to add a `\usepackage` statement with 4 [!] arguments in order to make the code compilable. Please don't make your readers go through needless and pointless guesswork.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some suggestions and comments:

- To switch the appearance of the third column from fully-justified to ragged-right, you should (a) load the packages `array` and `ragged2e` in the preamble and (b) change the column format of the third column from

  ```
  p{0.4\textwidth}
  ```

  to

  ```
  >{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{0.4\textwidth}
  ```
- Don't employ instructions such as `\bf` in a LaTeX document; use `\bfseries` instead.
- The position of the instruction `\begin{threeparttable}` is incorrect. It should be placed *before* `\caption`, and not before `\begin{tabular}`.
- You should probably also load the `babel` package with a suitable language option. (`spanish`, maybe?)

A full MWE that incorporates these points:

[image]

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{float,threeparttable,booktabs,fontspec}
\usepackage{array,ragged2e}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel} % is "spanish" correct?
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Estructura del guión de entrevista: apartados, componentes y temas}
\label{tab:guionentrevistas}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ll>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{0.4\textwidth}}
\toprule
\bfseries Apartado & {\bfseries Componente}\tnote{a} & \bfseries Tema \\
\midrule
Presentación  & Explicaciones & Proyecto, preguntas, registro, lenguaje, dinámica.\\
Descripciones & Perfil        & Formación, trayectoria, profesión.\\
Cuestionario  & Extensión 15M & Acciones, organización, entornos, actividades, opinión\\
    & Objetivos 15M    & Manifestaciones, acampadas, destinatarios\\
    & Estructura 15M   & Actores, procesos, roles, organigrama, herencias, gestión del consenso\\
    & Mentalidad 15M   & Ideas, orígenes, creencias\\
    & Comunicación 15M & Ideas\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}
      \small
      \item[a] Bla bla bla
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: With foreign languages and XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX, is better to use: 
    \usepackage[quiet]{polyglossia} 
    \setdefaultlanguage{spanish}
    \hyphenrules{spanish}

Comment: Thanks for your patience and your work Mico. Look at the results here, not working..https://es.sharelatex.com/project/5864e3382ff353be2d9589e5

Comment: @djnavas - I disagree. What is the basis for your claim? It is true that several years ago, `polyglossia` was indeed better than `babel` for use under XeLaTeX; on the other hand, several years ago, `polyglossia` didn't work at all with LuaLaTeX. Nowadays, however, both packages work fine with both XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX, at least for the "major" languages of the world. In my book, Spanish is one of the "major" languages. I'll readily confess, though, to having no idea how good either package is when it comes to dealing with the less-well-known languages of the world.

Comment: @JuanLinares If you change your documentclass from DissertateB5 to report, your table compiles without problems.

Comment: @JuanLinares - The sharelatex page shows that you wrote `\raggedright` rather than `\RaggedRight`, as I had written in my answer. Is this difference deliberate?

Comment: @Mico What I proposed about polyglossia is what is suggested in its manual. One important thing with Babel is that you get a finer control over how LaTeX manage some peculiarities of the spanish language. But in my experience here in Nicaragua, polyglossia is fine and does not need major ajustments for spanish,

Comment: @Mico - I just pasted your answer in to the chapter

Comment: @djnavas - There seems to be a discrepancy between your comments: First you state `polyglossia` is "better", later on you state that polyglossia is "fine" -- and presumably, no worse than but also no better than, `babel` -- when used with the `spanish` language option. For sure, I have absolutely no interest whatsover in getting dragged into a war of words over the relative merits of `babel` and `polyglossia`. The main point I *intended to make* (but, alas, apparently not successfully) in my answer is that it's a good idea to use a package that takes care of Spanish-language typesetting needs.

Comment: @JuanLinares - So, are you saying that the ShareLaTeX site software somehow changed the spelling from `\RaggedRight` to `\raggedright`? If that's the case, is there a way to suppress this rather unwelcome behavior?

Comment: @mico - I will write to the sharelatex support for that

Comment: @mico - Coming back to the answer. Changes made on sharelatex worked only for `\documentclass{book}` but not in my `\documentclass{DissertateB5}`

Comment: @JuanLinares - I've posted a screenshot so that you know what the table *should* look like if you manage to get around the quirks of the sharelatex software. :-)